# Django does not override template?

Tags: django

Please, help. What is wrong with this code? It does not override admin template in Django 1.7.3.

settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
    )

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (

    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',

)
```

templates/admin/base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('BOOKREADER site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">BOOKREADER administration</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have file system template loader set up:

```
# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

Also you can check in your `settings.py` that the folder exists

```
 import os
 assert os.path.exists(TEMPLATE_DIRS[0])  # Will fail on startup if your template dir is not properly set up
```

Comment: A working example: https://github.com/miohtama/LibertyMusicStore/blob/master/tatianastore/settings.py

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have template loaders inside my code. When I added assert at the end of settings.py it gives AssertionError. I am really stuck

Comment: Add a Python breakpoint before assert, inspect the contents of the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and fix it to match your setup.

Comment: If you are not familiar how to debug Python programs, here is a random tutorial for the starters for Python command line debugger: http://www.gregaker.net/2012/apr/05/debugging-python-with-pdb-or-ipdb/

Comment: I have used print to check my pathes. 1) print ("base dir path", BASE_DIR) -> C:\Users\Tulpor\workspace\tulpor
2) print ("new dir path", os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates').replace('\\','/')) -> C:/Users/Tulpor/workspace/tulpor/templates

Comment: If `os.path.exists` says the path does not exist on file system then whatever you have there is incorrect

Comment: Try look up more information if Windows path handling needs some special things to do. Not sure where did you pull the replace thing.

Comment: it was not code error. I created template folder, but named it like "tempate". Cheers